# Google Play Store: how to change "Offered By" for an app

Tags: android, google-play

I just uploaded my Android app to the Google Play Store and published it. Then I noticed that there's a *Offered By* and my developer name next to it. Is there anyway I can change what comes after *Offered By*?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can easily update your developer name using the Google Play Developer Console:

1. Sign in to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
2. Click **Settings**.
3. Next to "Developer name," type the developer name you want to be displayed on Google Play.
4. Near the top of your screen, click **Save**.

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139626

Comment: This will change the text that will be displayed under the app name, i'm talking about the `Offered By` text, you'll see that in the app page at the bottom

Comment: The developer name appears to users both under the name of your app and next to "Offered By". Could you please provide a link to the app where those two names are different?

Comment: After you update you will get the alert under name as "Your new developer name is pending approval. Users will see 'xxx' until your new name is approved." so just wait for that, that is what I am doing